# What are the measurements for a "Black Box"?

Tags: flight-data-recorder

I was wondering as to the measurements of  "black box" recorders. I have a new invention involving the "Black Box" and I need to know the measurements of the recorder.

Comment: you are `wondering` what, exactly? what quantities are measured? how often? why are recorded?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Are you asking what the physical dimensions are? Are you asking what data they record? Something else? Do you have specific recorders in mind? FDR vs CVR?

Comment: google ARINC429 to learn about the data bus aircraft use, and then read up on the ARINC standards defining what goes over the bus, then just record everything you see.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

The two main "black boxes" are the Flight Data Recorder (FDR) and the Cockpit Voice Recorder (CVR). These units are available from various manufacturers and therefore sizes vary. Many units can be used as either CVR or FDR, or as both.

A quick search provides a few examples:

**etep [Sentinel ED-112](http://www.etep.com/products/product.php?ID=29): CVR/FDR**
Height: 3.929 in (9.980 cm)
Width: 4.970 in (12.624 cm)
Depth: 6.907 in (17.545 cm)

**L3 [F1000](http://www.sea-avionics.com/lc/cart.php?target=productDetails&model=F1000&substring=): FDR**
Height: 7.62 in (19.4 cm)
Width: 4.88 in (12.4 cm)
Depth: 19.56 in (49.7 cm)

**Universal Avionics Systems [CVFDR](http://www.uasc.com/products/cvfdr.aspx): CVR/FDR**
Height 6.1 in (15.5 cm)
Width 4.9 in (12.4 cm)
Depth 8.0 in (20.3 cm)

**L3 [SRVIVR](http://www2.l-3com.com/edi/srvivr.htm): CVR/FDR**
standard configuration:
Height: 3.25 in (8.26 cm)
Width 5.55 in (14.1 cm)
Depth: 6.55 in (16.6 cm)
extended configuration:
Height: 3.25 in (8.26 cm)
Width: 5.55 in (14.1 cm)
Depth: 7.2 in (18.3 cm)

**L3 [FA2100](http://www.l-3ar.com/PDF_Files/MKT048_FA2100CVR.pdf): CVR**
Height 5.5 in. (14.00 cm)
Width 5.0 in. (12.70 cm)
Depth 12.6 in. (32.00 cm)

If you were asking something else, see:

[How much data do FDR and CVR generate on commercial jets?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/how-much-data-do-fdr-and-cvr-generate-on-commercial-jets)

Or other questions already asked here.